# Отладка C++ проекта в VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

У меня есть проект на C++ , функционал разных классов реализован в разных файлах, я могу успешно собрать этот проект в бинарный файл для запуска, но хотелось бы иметь возможность пошаговой отладки проекта в VSCode
Для этого я создал файл tasks.json с следующим содержанием

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "-Wall",
            "-pedantic",
            "-O3",
            "-std=c++11",
            "-Ilzpub/include",
            "-Inacc_sw/include",
            "-DNDEBUG",
            "/home/usr/examples/random_neuro_net/main.cc",
            "-o",
            "/home/usr/examples/exec",
            "-L.",
            "-Wl,-rpath,.",
            "-lnacc_gm",
            "-lboost_program_options"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
```

}

При запуске дебага в VsCode получаю ошибку

```
  > Executing task: g++ -g -Wall -pedantic -O3 -std=c++11 '-I lzpub/include' '-I nacc_sw/include' -DNDEBUG /home/usr/examples/random_neuro_net/main.cc -o /home/usr/examples/exec -L. -Wl,-rpath,. -lnacc_gm -lboost_program_options <

/home/usr/examples/random_neuro_net/main.cc:3:10: fatal error: nacc_test.h: No such file or directory
 #include <nacc_test.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
The terminal process "bash '-c', 'g++ -g -Wall -pedantic -O3 -std=c++11 '-I lzpub/include' '-I nacc_sw/include' -DNDEBUG /home/usr/examples/random_neuro_net/main.cc -o /home/usr/examples/exec -L. -Wl,-rpath,. -lnacc_gm -lboost_program_options'" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

я где-то допустил ошибку, либо что то упустил, в этом деле новенький
если есть какой-то способ подключить билд из makefile в дебагер vscode - буду рад его освоить

Comment: Приведенный tasks.json не соответствует сообщению об ошибке. Откуда там `'-I lzpub/include'`

Comment: @user7860670, после -std=c++11 :)

Comment: `tasks.json` имеет мало общего с отладкой. Вам нужен `launch.json`.

Comment: нет, после `-std=c++11` в tasks.json идет вовсе не `'-I lzpub/include'`